# Uncover values of one data frame with another mask data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have two data frames `A` and `B_mask`, where

```
A <- as.data.frame( matrix(1:20,nrow=4) )

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  5  9 13 17
2  2  6 10 14 18
3  3  7 11 15 19
4  4  8 12 16 20
```

And suppose also,

```
B_mask <- matrix(FALSE, nrow=4, ncol=5)
B_mask[2:3, 1:3] <- TRUE  
B_mask <- as.data.frame(B_mask) 

     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

How does one get a `result` data frame such that:

- If an entry in `B_mask` is equal to `TRUE`, uncover the corresponding value in `A`? For example, because `B_mask[2,1] = TRUE`, I would want `result[2,1] = A[2,1] = 2`.
- If an entry in `B_mask` is equal to `FALSE`, cover the corresponding value in `A` as `NA`? For example, because `B_mask[3,4] = FALSE`, I would want `result[3,4] = NA`.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you meant `res <- A;
 res[] <- as.matrix(A)[as.logical(NA^!B_mask)]`

Comment: @akrun Yes! Please put that as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We create a copy of the dataset ('res'), convert the 'FALSE' to NA in 'B_mask', and use the logical index to subset the corresponding values of 'A' and assign the output back to 'res' with the structure intact (`[]`)

```
res <- A
res[] <- as.matrix(A)[as.logical(NA^!B_mask)]
```

---

Or as @alexis_laz mentioned this can also done with

```
is.na(res) <- !as.matrix(B_mask)
```

Comment: Ditto what @StevenBeaupré said. +1

Comment: To avoid some arithmetic and coercion, an alternative seems to be `res = A; is.na(res) = !as.matrix(B_mask)`